# login page is not working in codeigniter with database postgresql

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

my admin login is always redirect back, but there is no error ?

this my database config in codeigniter

[image]

this my controller admin page

[image]

Comment: First, post your code as text instead of a photo so it can be copied. Second, I don't even see any questions here.

Comment: @AnhPham , the question is i have login admin page, when i'm trying input email and password. always redirect again to my admin login. i have check my config database and my controller, and my model correctly. so why always redirect again ?